# Text + randomchar doesn't work [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, math, random, document.write

```
<script>
function makeid()
{
var text = "var text = document.write(lastNumber);";
var possible = "*+-/";
for( var i=0; i < 1; i++ )
document.write(lastNumber + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
return text;
}
document.write(makeid(1))</script>
```

How do i make this to type for ex: 23* 45- 13/ and so on.
What is wrong?
It just show me 2 numbers and no char after.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this? `document.write` is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the code:

- You haven't specified the lastNumber parameter in the function.
- You are returning code that uses the parameter, but it's not reachable from where the code is executed.
- The returned code uses the return value of `document.write` although it doesn't return anything.
- The returned code doesn't have a script tag, so it will just be displayed on the page instead of executed.
- You are both writing the number in the function and returning code for writing it.

Also:

- You are using a loop that only loops once, which is pointless.

Just make the function return the string instead of returning code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeid(lastNumber) {
  var possible = "*+-/";
  return lastNumber + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
document.write(makeid(1));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function makeid()
{
var text = document.write(lastNumber);
var possible = "*-+/";
for( var i=0; i < 1; i++ )
text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
return text;
}
document.write(makeid(1))</script>
```

that worked but i get "88undefined+ " what is undefinded and how do i delete it?

Comment: It's the return value of `document.write` that is undefined. You are assinging that to the `text` variable, and then concatenating the string to it.