# Random char in a .js file

Tags: javascript, math, getelementbyid, var

This is the chars: `"*+-/";`

Javascript getElementById

How can i do `"randt"` to be 1 random char?

So if i type:

```
document.getElementById("sms-text").innerHTML = "" + random2 + randt;
```

It will be for ex `"22*"` or `"51+"`

How do i do it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you will take a random number 0-3, then find the character at that position;

```
var signs = "*+-/";

var signId = Math.floor(Math.random() * signs.length);

var sign = signs.charAt(signId);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "*+-/";
var random_char = str[Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)];
```

As the other answers point out, `str.charAt()` would also work.

Comment: Is that method of accessing a character supported in all browsers? I have a vague memory that IE doesn't like it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Matchu: Works in IE7 for me. Not sure about IE6 but I guess it works there, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do with a combination of [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```
var chars = "*+-/",
    randt = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
```

Note that you could replace `4` with `chars.length` if you don't know how many characters are in `chars`.

Comment: I'd replace the magic number `4` by `chars.length` even if you know the length of `chars` beforehand.

Comment: @Bart Kiers So would I, depending on how set-in-stone `chars` is.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just grab a random number from 0 to the length of the string and then cut the char out like so

```
var chars = "+-/";
var char = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
```

using `char` would be the random character

alternatively you can add the rand method to the prototype like so

```
String.prototype.randChar = function()
{
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
}
```

and then within any string created you can use like so

```
char = "+-.".randChar();
```

Comment: Standard Javascript implementations have no global `rand` function :/

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same question as you asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572026/text-randomchar-dosnt-work-javascript), only with the difference that you are using `innerHTML` instead of `document.write`. The way to produce the string is the same, so you can just use the function from my previous answer:

```
function makeid(lastNumber) {
  var possible = "*+-/";
  return lastNumber + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
```

Usage:

```
document.getElementById("sms-text").innerHTML = makeid(random2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var randt=['*','+','-','/'][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
```